# How to use 'this' with onClick to get attributes from the correct href

Tags: javascript, html

I have two forms with href for posting them, but just one **onClick** function. I want the javascript function to know which href has been clicked but can't really get `this` to work.. Should be an easy task but Im new to javascript! Would be helpfull if anyone could explain how should I use `this` in this context.

Code:

```js
function sendComment(){
 document.getElementById(this.getAttribute('data-id')).submit();
}
```

```html
<form id="submitComment1" action="<%= addComment %>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
   <aui:input style="width:95%;" type="text" value="<%=content%>" name="Content"></aui:input>
   <a href='' id="sc1" data-id="submitComment1" onClick="sendComment()">Comment</a>
</form>

<form id="submitComment2" action="<%= addComment %>" method="post"   enctype="multipart/form-data" >
   <aui:input style="width:95%;" type="text" value="<%=content%>" name="Content"></aui:input>
   <a href='' id="sc2" data-id="submitComment2" onClick="sendComment()">Comment</a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass *this* as argument.

```
onClick="sendComment(this)"//Pass this as argument


function sendComment(ele){
    document.getElementById(ele.getAttribute('data-id')).submit();
}
```

Comment: Done :) New to stackoverflow so didnt know! thanks again